# Getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in GWT 2.9 post compilation

Tags: javascript, java-8, gwt, gwt-2.8

I am getting `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` post compilation with GWT `2.9`.

[image]

After compiling with prettify flag during GWT compilation, I am able to see the transpiled JS code causing it. However, `Boolean.valueOf` is an in-built Java method.

[image]

I can see a never-ending recursive call happening here.

Comment: Don’t post text as pictures. Paste the text. The original source code of `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` is `return b? Boolean.TRUE: Boolean.FALSE;`, i.e. return value of either of the `static final` fields. There’s no calling into `valueOf` again. That must be an artifact of the translation.

Comment: @Holger I assume you are referring to Java Boolean source code. However, this issue is w.r.t GWT post compilation. Specifically [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/release/2.9.0/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Boolean.java#L65) . Post transpilation of java to JS this issue is causing.

Comment: In that linked code, `valueOf` calls `$create`, without recursion. And I already wrote that this “must be an artifact of the translation”.